# ElectronJS - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'whenReady')

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have this simple code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

    const createWindow = () => {
        const win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        })

        win.loadFile('index.html')
    }

    app.whenReady().then(() => {
        createWindow()
    })
}

myFunction()
```

When running this code with `node src/render.js` it throws this error:

```sh
/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/term-record/src/render.js:13
        app.whenReady().then(() => {
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'whenReady')
    at render (/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/term-record/src/render.js:13:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/term-record/src/render.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Note that I have Purposely Wrapped all the code inside a function!

- My Node Version: `v16.11.1`
- My NPM Version: `8.1.3`
- Electron version: `16.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and post a question here.
[Can't require('electron') successfully when build and run vscode source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70157967/17543103)

my problem resolved now, you can have a try, gl!